# what does MOV [LOCAL.9] ,0 represents in intel?

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering

Using a disassembler i found a instruction as MOV [LOCAL.9] ,0.
What does LOCAL represents ?
What will this instruction do ?
[image: MOV [LOCAL.9]]

Comment: I *guess* it means "9th local variable". Did you check the disassembler's manual if it exists?

Comment: Thanks i found it the disassembler manual

Comment: It's just a symbolic way to write `[ebp+offset]`